# Number of Unique `double`s between Two Values

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, numerical

*I provide an answer to this question below (I did not find an 'answer own question' button)*

## Original Question

In Java, we have floating point type `double` which is encoded as 64 bits in memory. From this we know that it can take on at most `2^64` possible values, minus some special values. We could enumerate all of them.

The routines `Math.nextUp(d)` and `Math.nextDown(d)`, given a `double` value `d`, will compute the one next larger and smaller `double`, respectively. Now I wonder how I can compute the number of `double` steps from one `double` `a` to `b`, i.e., my method `difference(a,b)` should work as follows:

```
assume a fixed, given a.

            b = ....               | difference(a, b)
===========================================================
   a                               |  0
   Math.nextUp(a)                  |  1
   Math.nextDown(a)                |  1
   Math.nextUp(Math.nextUp(a))     |  2
   Math.nextDown(Math.nextDown(a)) |  2
```

...and so on.

In the Java OpenJDK, the two mentioned methods are implemented as follows:

```
public static double nextUp(double d) {
  if( Double.isNaN(d) || d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
    return d;
  else {
    d += 0.0d;
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) +
                                    ((d >= 0.0d)?+1L:-1L));
  }
}
```

and

```
public static double nextDown(double d) {
  if (Double.isNaN(d) || d == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
    return d;
  else {
    if (d == 0.0)
      return -Double.MIN_VALUE;
    else
      return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) +
                                     ((d > 0.0d)?-1L:+1L));
  }
}
```

Can I safely do something similar, or does this only work because they only consider increments and decrements of `1`, i.e., may I run into trouble with the exponent? I strongly assume the latter case, and wonder what would be the right method to achieve my goal?

Again: I want this to work for arbitrary `double`s, i.e., `difference(1e-3,3.442e201)` should return the number `Math.nextUp` steps I would need to get from `1e-3` to `3.44e201`. Obviously, just iterating and counting `Math.nextUp` would not do in this scenario.

Many thanks,
  Thomas.

## Answer to Question

Thanks to the comments of @Thilo, it turns out that it actually is that easy to calculate the difference. Well, at least it sems to be that easy.

Here is the Java code:

```
/** Some mathematical utilities */
public final class MathUtils {

  /**
   * The number of unique {@code double} values between {@code a} and
   * {@code b}.
   * 
   * @param a
   *          the first {@code double}
   * @param b
   *          the second {@code double}
   * @return the steps between them, or {@code -1} if either value is
   *         {@link Double#NaN} or both are infinities of different signs
   */
  public static final long difference(final double a, final double b) {
    final long bitsA;
    double useA, useB, temp;

    if ((a != a) || (b != b)) { // take are of NaN
      return -1L;
    }
    useA = (a + 0d);
    useB = (b + 0d);
    if (useA > useB) {
      temp = useB;
      useB = useA;
      useA = temp;
    }
    if (useA == useB) {
      return 0L;
    }
    if (useA <= Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
      return -1L;
    }
    if (useB >= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
      return -1L;
    }

    if (useA < 0d) {
      bitsA = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(-useA);
      if (useB < 0d) {
        return (bitsA - Double.doubleToRawLongBits(-useB));
      }
      return (bitsA + Double.doubleToRawLongBits(useB));
    }
    return (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(useB)
        - Double.doubleToRawLongBits(useA));
  }
}
```

and here some rudimentary JUnit test to confirm whether the results are what they should be:

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;


/**
 * A test for math utils
 */
public class MathUtilsTest {

  /** the constructor */
  public MathUtilsTest() {
    super();
  }

  /** test step difference between two values */
  @Test(timeout = 3600000)
  public void testDifferenceBetweenTwoValues() {
    final Random random;
    double start, end;
    int starts, iteration;

    random = new Random();

    for (starts = 333; (--starts) >= 0;) {
      end = start = -(1d / Math.log(1d - random.nextDouble()));
      for (iteration = 0; iteration < 3333; iteration++) {
        Assert.assertEquals(iteration, MathUtils.difference(start, end));
        Assert.assertEquals(iteration, MathUtils.difference(end, start));
        end = Math.nextUp(end);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * test the "step" difference of two values, one of which is negative,
   * the other one being positive
   */
  @Test(timeout = 3600000)
  public void testDifferenceBetweenTwoValuesOfDifferentSign() {
    double start, end;
    int iteration;

    end = start = 0d;
    for (iteration = 0; iteration < 333333; iteration++) {
      Assert.assertEquals(
          (MathUtils.difference(start, 0d) + //
              MathUtils.difference(0d, end)),
          MathUtils.difference(start, end));
      Assert.assertEquals(
          (MathUtils.difference(start, 0d) + //
              MathUtils.difference(0d, end)),
          MathUtils.difference(end, start));
      start = Math.nextAfter(start, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
      end = Math.nextUp(end);
    }
  }

  /** test the border cases of the step difference */
  @Test(timeout = 3600000)
  public void testDifferenceBetweenTwoValuesBorderCases() {
    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(0d, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(0d, -0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(-0d, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(-0d, -0d));

    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(0d, Double.MIN_VALUE));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_VALUE, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(-0d, Double.MIN_VALUE));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_VALUE, -0d));

    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(0d, -Double.MIN_VALUE));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_VALUE, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(-0d, -Double.MIN_VALUE));
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_VALUE, -0d));

    Assert.assertEquals(2L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_VALUE, -Double.MIN_VALUE));
    Assert.assertEquals(2L,
        MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE));

    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(0d, Double.MIN_NORMAL));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_NORMAL, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(-0d, Double.MIN_NORMAL));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_NORMAL, -0d));

    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(0d, -Double.MIN_NORMAL));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_NORMAL, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(-0d, -Double.MIN_NORMAL));
    Assert.assertEquals((1L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_NORMAL, -0d));

    Assert.assertEquals((2L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(Double.MIN_NORMAL, -Double.MIN_NORMAL));
    Assert.assertEquals((2L << 52L),
        MathUtils.difference(-Double.MIN_NORMAL, Double.MIN_NORMAL));

    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(0L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
        Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, Double.NaN));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Double.NaN));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Double.NaN));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(0d, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(0d, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(0d, Double.NaN));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, 0d));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(1d, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(1d, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(1d, Double.NaN));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 1d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 1d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, 1d));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(-1d, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(-1d, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(-1d, Double.NaN));

    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, -1d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L,
        MathUtils.difference(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, -1d));
    Assert.assertEquals(-1L, MathUtils.difference(Double.NaN, -1d));
  }
}
```

I'd be thankful for any counter-indications or issues not yet covered by the code.

Cheers,
   Thomas.

Comment: It seems you could just take the `doubleToRawLongBits` of the two values and subtract them (plus some extra logic to take care of the sign, crossing zero, and Inf/NaN).

Comment: I also sort of think that way, but I am not sure whether it is numerically safe? The `long` representation of the numbers should contain one bit for sign, 11 bits for the exponent, and 52 bits for the mantissa/fraction. If the two numbers have exponents several steps apart, will subtracting them still work reliably? ... I will see if I can test and verify this, but am unsure about whether I can test for all border cases correctly.

Comment: Since all `nextUp` does is add one, the results of a subtraction should be consistent with the number of steps.

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. It would be equivalent to doing many `nextUp`s. ...I don't know what I  was concerned about anymore...

Comment: `We could enumerate all of them`. No, it'll take you ~18,446,744,074 seconds or ~585 years to enumerate all 2^64 values if you can list 1 billion values in 1s

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: exactly ^_^. However, based on Thilo's reassuring comments, I could figure out a solution which seems to work :-)

Comment: to answer your own question, you can simply type the answer in the box below just like answering anybody else's questions

Comment: Hm, now I see it. Yesterday that box wasn't there. Strange. Maybe I accidentally logged out. Well, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could just take the `doubleToRawLongBits` of the two values and subtract them (plus some extra logic to take care of the sign, crossing zero, and Inf/NaN).

Since all `nextUp` does is add one, the results of a subtraction should be consistent with the number of steps.